# Installshield 2015 : minor upgrade (Update.exe) not replacing files for one feature

Tags: .net-assembly, updates, installshield

In Installshield 2015 Premier Edition, I've created a patch definition which upgrades my application product from version 1.9.7 to 1.9.7.5

In the Installscript MSI project, I've only changed package code, product version and built the patch (Latest 1.9.7.5 release - Previous 1.9.7 release).

Patch (Update.exe) is executed under Admin priviliges (a 1.9.7 release in installed priorly)

The patch 1.9.7.5 will omit to update .exe and .dll component files of a feature application directly install in [INSTALLDIR] (root : C:\ProgramFiles\MYCOMPANY\MYAPP\confapp.exe)

All other component files are updated respectfully ; they're located in their own sub-directories of [INSTALLDIR] as designed in Installation Architecture in IS2015.

C:\ProgramFiles\MYCOMPANY\MYAPP\Feature1DIR\app1.exe
 C:\ProgramFiles\MYCOMPANY\MYAPP\Feature2DIR\app2.exe
 C:\ProgramFiles\MYCOMPANY\MYAPP\Feature3DIR\app3.exe
 C:\ProgramFiles\MYCOMPANY\MYAPP\Feature4DIR\app4.exe
 C:\ProgramFiles\MYCOMPANY\MYAPP\Feature5DIR\app5.exe

I'm shipping the newly built applications and have upgraded my .dll files with AssemblyInfo.cs.

Long story short, my Update.exe is only updating 5 out of 6 applications installed.

Any help appreciated if you've already encountered the issue,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add your feature/component/file structure and log file entries that relate to those files in particular? It should look something like:

```
MSI (s) (B4:4C) [11:30:07:906]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=eulatxt|eula.txt,SourceCabKey=FILE1,DestName=eula.txt,Attributes=512, FileSize=29239,PerTick=32768,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,, CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=58982400,HashOptions=0, HashPart1=-1713153497,HashPart2=58557210, HashPart3=1046945815,HashPart4=871163290,,)
MSI (s) (B4:4C) [11:30:07:906]: File: C:\WINDOWS\system32\eula.txt; Won’t Overwrite; Won’t patch; Existing file is unversioned but modified
```

You also need to check your components and key files. If the key file for a component is not changing in your patch (this is a "small update" or "patch" BTW, not minor upgrade), none of the other files in the component get upgraded regardless of the version changes associated. Remember that component best practices state one binary (versioned) file per component.

From this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204770(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Be aware how the Windows Installer applies the File Versioning Rules
>   when Replacing Existing Files. The Windows Installer first determines
>   whether the component's key file is already installed before
>   attempting to install any of the files of the component. If the
>   installer finds a file with the same name as the component's key file
>   installed in the target location, it compares the version, date, and
>   language of the two key files and uses file versioning rules to
>   determine whether to install the component provided by the package. If
>   the installer determines it needs to replace the component base upon
>   the key file, then it uses the file versioning rules on each installed
>   file to determine whether to replace the file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm building a minor upgrade patch because I've changed both package code and product version in the .ism project. Thanks, I'll follow the MSDN article and let you know.

Comment: I would like to provide you the log file entries but I don't know to generate it during patch execution; I understand it's a verbose log which can be generated by command line when launching update.exe but the command line remains uncertain.

Comment: When you create the patch, you can specify to create the log file, and by default that goes to `%TEMP%` For options on how to create the log file in Update.exe look in the InstallShield help file for **Update.exe**. I know for regular InstallShield bootstrappers it's `setup.exe /V"/l*v logfile.txt"`.

Comment: But in your original question, you say you're creating a patch definition and only changing package code and version. Which is it?

Comment: I change the package code by clicking the "Generate new GUID" button on the IS2015 GUI.
I also change product version from 1.00.0000 to 1.9.7.5 in General section of General Informations.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an InstallScript project, open Components view and make sure OverWrite setting is set to Always. By default, it is set to Overwrite files by version, then Date, I think. However, I have seen cases when this algorithm did not work for some reason, and some files were not updated.